# Redirecting conditionally on the bases of a specific directory used in URL

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, conditional-statements

How am I supposed to set up a  web page (HTML) that will redirect conditionally?
That is, the user must be directed to ***domain2.com/xyz*** only if the user had initially gone to ***domain1.com/abc/xyz*** and NOT any other URL like ***domain1.com/pqr/xyz*** or ***domain1.com/xyz***

Comment: What do you mean by 'user had initially gone to?'. Does it mean that if current url is 'domain1.com/abc/xyz' then redirect to 'domain2.com/xyz' ?

Comment: @budhram Yes, that was what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your suggestion guys!

I believe the best way to solve this was using ***.htaccess*** as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
if(location.href === 'http://aaa.com' ){
  location.href = 'http://bbb.com';
} else {
  location.href = 'http://espn.go.com/';
}
```

**[DEMO LINK](http://jsbin.com/egEvOVO/3)**

Answer (score 0):

try this js script

```
if(document.URL=='domain1.com/abc/xyz')
{
  location.href='domain2.com/xyz ';
}
```

append `http://` or `https://` as per your requirement befor `domain1` and `domain2`